# Why I can not use " import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit' " in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redux

guys

I am learning redux, and try to run a very simple example code in node.js environment. I got the following error when I try to use :

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit' .
```

The errors is:

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'createSlice' not found. The requested module '@reduxjs/toolkit' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
const { createSlice, configureStore } = pkg;

at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:120:21)
at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:165:5)
at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

If I use import like what the error tip says:

```
import pkg from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
const { createSlice, configureStore } = pkg;
```

All is OK.

What I want to ask is:
**It gives me a wrong example in the official website of Redux? Or Just I run the example with a wrong way?**

The following is the detail information.

My Node.js version is: **v14.17.3**

1 Init a node project:

```
mkdir redux_01
cd redux_01
yarn init
yarn add @reduxjs/toolkit
```

2 Modify the 'package.json', add a line in it:

```
"type":"module"
```

3 Create a file 'index.js' with the "Redux Toolkit Example" code parsed from https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started.

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    value: 0
  },
  reducers: {
    incremented: state => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.value += 1
    },
    decremented: state => {
      state.value -= 1
    }
  }
})

export const { incremented, decremented } = counterSlice.actions

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: counterSlice.reducer
})

// Can still subscribe to the store
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

// Still pass action objects to `dispatch`, but they're created for us
store.dispatch(incremented())
// {value: 1}
store.dispatch(incremented())
// {value: 2}
store.dispatch(decremented())
// {value: 1}
```

4 Now I run it like this:

```
node index.js
```

I then got that error message that I just mentioned.

Comment: Are you not using a bundler like webpack? `@reduxjs/toolkit` appears to only support being imported as an ES module via bundled code (its package.json file has a `module` property, but no `exports` property, and its `main` is a CommonJS module)

Comment: Hi, Aurast, Thanks for your reply. I try to keep everything as simple as possible, so I have not used webpack to run it.  Because I just want to understand the core concepts of redux and don't want to mix it with React. If my code is fine, then it looks like nodejs can't handle this and will have to configure webpack to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is explained here:
https://lightrun.com/answers/reduxjs-redux-toolkit-cannot-import-redux-toolkit-from-a-nodejs-esm-module "here"

solution:

```
import * as toolkitRaw from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
const { createSlice,configureStore } = toolkitRaw.default ?? toolkitRaw;
or in Typescript:

import * as toolkitRaw from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
```